# How to add resources to two modular jars in same-named folders?

Tags: java, java-9, java-platform-module-system, java-17

Assuming we have two jar files with two different modules. Both jar-files include some resources (lets say png-files) in a folder called images in their jar. When I now try to start a module in java I get the following error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.LayerInstantiationException: Package images in both module A and module B
```

Although my images folder is not meant to be a package but is just a folder containing resources. So how can I get two modules with an images-folder onto my module-path?

Comment: I'm fairly sure, but not positive, that the way you're expected to solve this is to simply disambiguate them: e.g. `foo.bar.images` and `foo.bazz.images`.

Comment: The rule is that anything that looks like a package is treated as a package, so you could try putting the files in META-INF/images instead. Not sure if it works, but easy to try.

Comment: Before the introduction of the module system, looking up the resources starting with `/images` could unpredictably end up in arbitrary results of either jar file. Now, the module system is telling you that there’s a problem. Why do you insist on storing resources in paths with name clashes?

Comment: As Holger wrote: different modules, different packages. Make use of the ServiceLoader SPI to find multiple service implemenations including sources of resources at runtime. The auto-merging powers of the class-path don't work in the modular world.

Answer (score 4):

> How to add resources to two modular jars in same-named folders?

While it is possible to do this by putting the resources under a path that is not a valid package name, such as `META-INF/resources` or another path with a `-` hyphen in it, I would advice against doing so since such resources are not encapsulated, and might not be uniquely identifiable with some APIs.

In other words: ANY code in the application can load a resource that is not inside a valid package, not just the code of the module in the jar that contains the resource.

As well as: if the resource does not have a unique name based on it's path inside the jar, only one of the resources with the same name can be found by the `ClassLoader.findResource` API.

---

My advice would be to create a package in your module that has the same name as the module, with the `.images` suffix. e.g. `mod.foo.images`, and then put your resources in that package. Then load the resource with the [modular resource loading API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Module.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)):

```
MyClass.class.getModule().getResourceAsStream("mod/foo/images/my_image.jpg")
```

That way the resource would only be loadable by code in the same module (`mod.foo`, as long as you put it on the module path), as well as avoiding any ambiguity with resource names.